# How many independent scalars can we make from a tensor?

Tags: tensor-calculus

A symmetric tensor $T^{\mu\nu}$ in 4D has 10 components. But it depends on a coordinate system. How many independent scalars can we make from $T$. We can make no more than 10, (otherwise they will be equations between them) but if we wanted to express the invariants of $T$ in a coordinate independent way, as a list of scalars how would be do it? I can imagine a few:

$$C_1  = T^{\mu}_\mu$$
$$C_2 = T^{\mu\nu}T_{\mu\nu}$$
$$C_3 = T^{\mu\nu}T_{\nu\sigma}T^\sigma_\mu$$
$$...$$
$$D_1 = \det(T) = \varepsilon_{abcd}\varepsilon_{fghi}T^{af}T^{bg}T^{ch}T^{di}$$
(Well $D_1$ could be written in terms of $C_4,C_3,C_2,C_1$.)

And do they have names? For example if we are thinking about the Ricci tensor, $C_1$ is the Ricci scalar, and $C_2$ has an interpretation as the magnitude of the tensor to test how close it is to being zero. What does $C_3$ and $C_4$ mean?

These invariants seem to cover all the coordinate independent properties of a tensor.

(For a vector $A^{\mu}$ there is only the length-squared $A^\mu A_\mu$ even though it may have 100 components)

Bonus: What about a higher order tensor $T^{\mu\nu..}$?